# .sublime-syntax multiple line function detection

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, regex-lookarounds, specman

I'm writing a [.sublime-syntax for the Specman language](https://github.com/tsvi/Specman) and need help with multiple line method declaration.

A method is declared using the keyword `is` which comes after most of the other parts of the method declaration.

E.g.

```
fwd_init() @driver.clock is {
```

or

```
add(x : uint, y : uint) is also {
```

or

```
private do_stuff(field : my_type) is only {
```

etc...

My problem is that parts of the declaration can be quite long in case a lot of parameters are passed to the method, so I tend to split the line to multiple lines.

I'm having trouble matching the syntax for the method, as I need multiple line matches.

The following is what I have currently, but it's not working:

```
methods:
- match: (?=^\s*(?:private|static|final)?\s+[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?\s*\()
  set:
    - match: (?=\bis\b)
      push: method-declaration
```

Basically I want to return to lookahead, possibly match for the function, in case it's not a function pop it.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing the question I realized, all I needed to do is push the `method-declaration` onto the stack and first of all do a negative lookahead for `is`.

As follows:

```
methods:
  - match: (?=^\s*(?:private|static|final)?\s+[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?\s*\()
    push: method-declaration

method-declaration:
  - match: (?!is(?:\s+)(only|first|also)?)
    pop: true
  - ... parsing of the method declaration
```

Hope this helps anybody else looking for info on the subject.